# Dont show logout Anyway

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a Laravel project. When I login to web site and redirect user to home page I want to Change the login icon to logout but it doesn't work.

this is my blade :

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" class="navbar-brand">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Logout"></span>
    </a>
@else
    <a href="{{ url('/signin') }}" class="navbar-brand">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Login"></span>
    </a>
@endif
```

This is my controller :

```
$data = Input::except(array('_token','signin'));

if(Auth::attempt($data)) {
    return redirect('/');
} else {
    return redirect('/login')->with('loginstatus','user not found!');
}
```

Comment: I test your code, it's ok for me! please explain more

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I dont know I am confused. I doesnt work ... Maybe be you have something that i dont have it ...May it?

Comment: When I enter /logout manually after login it shows this error [Route [login] not defined.]

Comment: What do your routes look like then?
EDIT: Also looks like you should be using `/signin` in your controller if that is what your route is using, like in the blade.

Comment: Route[login] not defined solved but Auth::user not work and always return false and @else execute...

Comment: Just name the login root in your web file by adding `->name('login');` in to the end of it.

Comment: This is just an example ; `Route::get('signin', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');`

Comment: I do all of them my friend but its not working ... It make me so angry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default laravel logout route use `POST` method, but your code you are using `GET` method, you should update your code like this,

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" class="navbar-brand"  onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Logout"></span>
    </a>
    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                </form>
    @else
        <a href="{{ url('/signin') }}" class="navbar-brand">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Login"></span>
        </a>

@endif
```

I hope this will help you.